# FIrebase test lab app showing no internet page only

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab

I am using this code for test internet connection

```
public boolean isConnected() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    final String command = "ping -c 1 google.com";
    return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor() == 0;
}
```

and my app is working fine in real device 
It contain internet permission

Answer (score 0):

Try Specifying the path of ping.

> system/bin/ping

Make sure that you have added internet permission.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

```
final String command = "system/bin/ping -c 1 google.com";
```

**Edit:** Qemu Emulator does not directly support ICMP Traffic by default. That means you cannot run ping command as a guest. So  you may need to change network settings in the emulator. [You can refer here for more details](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#User_Networking_.28SLIRP.29).

So may be it does not work on virtual devices.

Comment: and my app is working fine in real device 
It contain internet permission

Comment: @Midhilaj Ok .Try to post an update here on this issue.

Comment: now i am little busy with  fixing bug and after complecting my bug fixing task i will test agane

Comment: Instead of just checking for a zero exit code, you might want to log any error message/details to see exactly why it is failing.